# Getting camera preview FPS in android camera2 api

Tags: android

How can I calculate the current frame rate of the camera preview in camera2 API?
I know that if I could access the callback function of each preview I could use the elapsed time to find the FPS. I used onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) function but it doesn't seem to work and the UI gets stuck.